ExtJS graphic order book
I am creating an order book using Extjs. In the requirements I have to create it by building it with components from Extjs. Performance is important here because the data is often refreshed.
I need to build the structure as in the image below. I'm wondering how to approach this wisely and build a good component here, to which in the future will be added a lot of functionality, so it is important to plan it well from the beginning.
On the left are BUY orders and on the right are SELL orders. In the middle is the amount and price of the order. The next lines are, of course, other price levels. This is displayed in the middle column.
When buy and sell transactions meet during the open market, the transaction appears on the other side for a while, after which the corresponding amount will be deleted.
Can anyone help to get it right how to build such a component and add transactions accordingly ?

Generally speaking I would try it with a grid but if there are variable number of buy and sell orders at a specific price level (which I guess there are) it can be challenging. In order to get good answers on SO I would recommend to post more specific questions and also include the code you have tried so far.

Here are some hints. Are the buy and sell orders grouped? Are they ASC? If you answer these I can futher help. Are you stuck in 4.2?

thanks for the answer. I added a more detailed structure of the incoming data that I parsed into something like this. Sorry, I chose the wrong tag - now it's ok. Extjs version 7.5 @Dinkheller

The Answer is correct. If you need to change the data, please add a new question and we can help you change the data using a reader or using an ajax call and change the data onSuccess. If you add a new question, please add more data.

I would go with renderers inside a grid.
Here is an example (did not sort it nor use groupers, it all depends on the data):
renderer: function(value, gridcell, record) {
    value = record.get('sell')[3];

    if (value) {gridcell.tdCls = 'sell';}
    else {gridcell.tdCls = '';}

    return value;
}


And here is a Fiddle, which shows how it works:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3rjo
The data structure should not matter. You can change the data the way you need it, using a custom reader:
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/classic/Ext.data.reader.Reader.html

in renderer you added record.get('sell')[3], [2], [1], [0]. I would like to do it in a loop because I can have a maximum of 23 elements in one line. I'm trying to add a for loop, but instead of several elements, I only get one element per line.

Just write your own renderer (String => viewController). Each column gets a custom property dataAction and Inside the custom renderer you can read dataAction and you just have to write the code once. I updated the fiddle, but next time please add a new question to stackoverflow, so that everyone can help. Cheers
